# The method makeType() is undefined for the type TitanGraph

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, titan, gremlin

I'm trying to create one Titan Graph Example but it is giving error.

I'm having pom.xml as follows :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion
    <groupId>com.titanobwebservices.services</groupId>
    <artifactId>titanob-services</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>titanob-services Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-berkeleyje</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.thinkaurelius.titan</groupId>
            <artifactId>titan-es</artifactId>
            <version>0.4.4</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>titanob-services</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

GodOfGraphFactory.java as follows :

```
package com.titanos.webservices;

import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_BACKEND_KEY;
import static com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY;

import java.io.File;

import org.apache.commons.configuration.BaseConfiguration;
import org.apache.commons.configuration.Configuration;

import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanFactory;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanGraph;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.TitanKey;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.core.attribute.Geoshape;
import com.thinkaurelius.titan.graphdb.configuration.GraphDatabaseConfiguration;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.ElementHelper;

public class GraphOfTheGodsFactory {

    public static final String INDEX_NAME = "search";


    public static TitanGraph create(final String directory) {
        BaseConfiguration config = new BaseConfiguration();
        Configuration storage = config.subset(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_NAMESPACE);
        // configuring local backend
        storage.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_BACKEND_KEY, "local");
        storage.setProperty(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY, directory);
        // configuring elastic search index
        Configuration index = storage.subset(GraphDatabaseConfiguration.INDEX_NAMESPACE).subset(INDEX_NAME);
        index.setProperty(INDEX_BACKEND_KEY, "elasticsearch");
        index.setProperty("local-mode", true);
        index.setProperty("client-only", false);
        index.setProperty(STORAGE_DIRECTORY_KEY, directory + File.separator + "es");

        TitanGraph graph = TitanFactory.open(config);
        GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(graph);
        return graph;
    }

    public static void load(final TitanGraph graph) {

        graph.makeType().name("name").dataType(String.class).indexed(Vertex.class).unique(Direction.BOTH).makePropertyKey();
        graph.makeType().name("age").dataType(Integer.class).indexed(INDEX_NAME, Vertex.class).unique(Direction.OUT).makePropertyKey();
        graph.makeType().name("type").dataType(String.class).unique(Direction.OUT).makePropertyKey();

        final TitanKey time = graph.makeType().name("time").dataType(Integer.class).unique(Direction.OUT).makePropertyKey();
        final TitanKey reason = graph.makeType().name("reason").dataType(String.class).indexed(INDEX_NAME, Edge.class).unique(Direction.OUT).makePropertyKey();
        graph.makeType().name("place").dataType(Geoshape.class).indexed(INDEX_NAME, Edge.class).unique(Direction.OUT).makePropertyKey();

        graph.makeType().name("father").unique(Direction.OUT).makeEdgeLabel();
        graph.makeType().name("mother").unique(Direction.OUT).makeEdgeLabel();
        graph.makeType().name("battled").primaryKey(time).makeEdgeLabel();
        graph.makeType().name("lives").signature(reason).makeEdgeLabel();
        graph.makeType().name("pet").makeEdgeLabel();
        graph.makeType().name("brother").makeEdgeLabel();

        graph.commit();

        // vertices

        Vertex saturn = graph.addVertex(null);
        saturn.setProperty("name", "saturn");
        saturn.setProperty("age", 10000);
        saturn.setProperty("type", "titan");

        Vertex sky = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(sky, "name", "sky", "type", "location");

        Vertex sea = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(sea, "name", "sea", "type", "location");

        Vertex jupiter = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(jupiter, "name", "jupiter", "age", 5000, "type", "god");

        Vertex neptune = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(neptune, "name", "neptune", "age", 4500, "type", "god");

        Vertex hercules = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(hercules, "name", "hercules", "age", 30, "type", "demigod");

        Vertex alcmene = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(alcmene, "name", "alcmene", "age", 45, "type", "human");

        Vertex pluto = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(pluto, "name", "pluto", "age", 4000, "type", "god");

        Vertex nemean = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(nemean, "name", "nemean", "type", "monster");

        Vertex hydra = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(hydra, "name", "hydra", "type", "monster");

        Vertex cerberus = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(cerberus, "name", "cerberus", "type", "monster");

        Vertex tartarus = graph.addVertex(null);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(tartarus, "name", "tartarus", "type", "location");

        // edges

        jupiter.addEdge("father", saturn);
        jupiter.addEdge("lives", sky).setProperty("reason", "loves fresh breezes");
        jupiter.addEdge("brother", neptune);
        jupiter.addEdge("brother", pluto);

        neptune.addEdge("lives", sea).setProperty("reason", "loves waves");
        neptune.addEdge("brother", jupiter);
        neptune.addEdge("brother", pluto);

        hercules.addEdge("father", jupiter);
        hercules.addEdge("mother", alcmene);
        ElementHelper.setProperties(hercules.addEdge("battled", nemean), "time", 1, "place", Geoshape.point(38.1f, 23.7f));
        ElementHelper.setProperties(hercules.addEdge("battled", hydra), "time", 2, "place", Geoshape.point(37.7f, 23.9f));
        ElementHelper.setProperties(hercules.addEdge("battled", cerberus), "time", 12, "place", Geoshape.point(39f, 22f));

        pluto.addEdge("brother", jupiter);
        pluto.addEdge("brother", neptune);
        pluto.addEdge("lives", tartarus).setProperty("reason", "no fear of death");
        pluto.addEdge("pet", cerberus);

        cerberus.addEdge("lives", tartarus);

        // commit the transaction to disk
        graph.commit();
    }
}
```

but I'm getting following error..

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: The method makeType() is undefined for the type TitanGraph
    at com.titanos.webservices.GraphOfTheGodsFactory.load(GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java:52)
    at com.titanos.webservices.GraphOfTheGodsFactory.create(GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java:46)
    at com.titanos.webservices.exampletest.main(exampletest.java:13)
```

I've attached the screen shot as well..

[image]

I'm unable to find which dependency I'm missing in this project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a compilation error because there is no method `makeType()` on TitanGraph. If you look at the [Titan 0.4.4 javadoc](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/javadoc/0.4.4/com/thinkaurelius/titan/core/TitanGraph.html) for TitanGraph, you will see the available methods. See also the [migration notes](http://thinkaurelius.github.io/titan/wikidoc/0.4.0/Upgrade-Instructions.html) from Titan 0.3.2 to 0.4.0 which point out the breaking changes in the API. [GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java](https://github.com/pluradj/titan/blob/0.4.4/titan-core/src/main/java/com/thinkaurelius/titan/example/GraphOfTheGodsFactory.java) is packaged in Titan itself, so you can see from that code how to define the schema correctly.

Titan 0.4.4 was release almost 2 years ago. Titan 1.0.0 was released in September 2015, and it would be a better starting point if you are getting started with Titan. Visit the [Titan homepage](http://titandb.io) for more details and documentation for all versions. Make sure you match the documentation with the version you are building against.